# Registered temp table missing in Spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I tried to take data from csv and load it into spark sql.

I have given my sample csv and my code below.

When I execute the code I'm getting error saying that Table not found. its very strange to me because same code was working till yesterday.

Sample csv:

[image]

My code:

```
val a=sc.textFile("D:/TFS/winutils/files/New_York1.csv"); 
val b=a.first();val c=a.filter(p=> p!=b);
case class mytest(Year:Int,Region:String,Sex:String)

val d=c.map(_.split(",",-1)).map(p=> mytest(p(0).toInt,p(1),p(2)))
val e=d.toDF()

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

e.registerTempTable("xyz")
sqlContext.sql("select * from xyz where  Region like 'Asia%'").count

Error:
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: xyz;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.getTable(Analyzer.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$9.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:315)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$9.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:281)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
```

can someone please help to fix this issue??
im using spark 1.6 version.

Comment: Did you check that the input file exists? what is the result of `e.show()` ?

Comment: Are you looking for a simpler solution for reading CSV file into dataframe or would like to debug the reason why your code doesn't work?

Comment: e.show() is working and it shows data. i want to know why the code is not working today and it was working yesterday.

Comment: If you didn't change the code, and it worked yesterday and doesn't work today it might be related to environment reason. What happen when you reboot your computer and execute the code again after reboot?

Comment: Can you create a minimum **complete** and verifiable example please ? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If you're working with CSV, you probably should be using Spark2 or at least import the spark-csv package